# SQL Server - query find users with most popular keywords

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

In SQL Server 2014 I have a table look_table that lists all the keywords (with duplicates) that users have been looking for in my app with related user_id. So the table has 2 columns: keyword, user_id.

GOAL: Select 3 most popular keywords in table and find all users that was looking for all of these 3 keywords.

What I have so far is to list 3 most popular keywords:

```
select top 3 keyword
from look_table
group by keyword
order by count(*) desc
```

But I can't get users which have been looking for all of these keywords. It would be great if someone will help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all three, then that is a bit tricky.  Here is one method:

```
with k as (
      select top 3 keyword
      from look_table
      group by keyword
      order by count(*) desc
     )
select lt.user_id
from look_table lt join
     k
     on lt.keyword = k.keyword
group by lt.user_id
having count(distinct lt.keyword) = 3;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a subquery:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM look_table
WHERE keyword IN (
  select top 3 keyword
  from look_table
  group by keyword
)
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING count(distinct keyword) = 3
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this will select users that have been looking for all of this 3 keywords or maybe just for any of them?

Comment: You're right. It find users looking for any of the three keywords. I missed the "all" - requirement.

Comment: Edited. It should respect the "all" - requirement, now.

Comment: Thank you for your answets, it looks like its working